# Electron で Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned

Tags: javascript, electron

Electron(v22)でファイルのアップロードする部分を作成しています。
renderer.tsからpreload.tsを経由してbackground.tsを経由するときに、
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned.`
がrenderer.ts部分で発生してしまいます。

原因がわからず、またどの部分が問題なのか予測がつかなくて、修正ができない状態です。
問題発生のポイント、原因、できましたら対応方法などアドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

### renderer.ts

```
holder.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    const files = event.dataTransfer.files;

    const file = files[0];
    window.electronAPI.uploadFile(file)
    // ↑Uncaught (in promise) Error: An object could not be cloned.というエラーが出る

    holder.innerText = "処理中..."
});
```

### preload.ts

```
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron')

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electronAPI',{
    // @ts-ignore
    uploadFile: (file) => ipcRenderer.invoke('file:upload', file)
})
```

### background.ts

```
async function handleFileUpload(event,file) {
    let text = await fs.readFileSync(file.path, 'utf8');
    json = jsonFromText(text); // jsonはグローバル変数
}
ipcMain.handle('file:upload', handleFileUpload)
```

phpstormを使って、background.ts にブレークポイントを設置しましたが、
停止しないので、background.tsにもたどり着いていないように思えます。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ipcRenderer.invoke()`](https://www.electronjs.org/ja/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) は[構造化複製アルゴリズム](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Structured_clone_algorithm)を使って引数をコピーするそうで、`File` オブジェクトは対象外です。レンダラー側で `TypedArray` に読み込んでから送るのがいいんじゃないでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど file object だからエラーになっていたんですね。"クローンが作れない"というエラーの意味に納得しました。TypedArrayへの変換方法がわからなかったので、オブジェクトの各要素名から新しい配列を作ることで解決することが出来ました。